# Use template string in render() instead of an imported template html file

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible to use the render method of a LWC component to return a template string ie:

```
render() {
    `<template>Stuff here</template>`
}
```

This would allow things to be more dynamic with complex, nested, data driven use cases we have and are currently using react for (it's composition capabilities make these sorts of use cases very easy).

Answer (score 1):

In that way no - you can`t return string values. What you can do is to create separate html files, import them in your component and then return them (conditionally )in the render function.

Comment: Thanks Renji - I was expecting that answer but hoping there was a way. Do you know any different way to polymorphcally compose components then? For example if I have a dynamic form builder of say 1 -> n items where n is determined at run time where position 2 onwards could be a text input component, a checkbox, select etc depending on previous input's values which we don't know at coding/compile time.

Comment: Not that i am aware of. I guess as of today the most dynamics which you can get is conditional rendering in the template itself or to have multiple independent templates files.

There is a rfc for adding dynamic component support (https://github.com/salesforce/lwc-rfcs/pull/10) - so you may want to monitor the release notes in the future for it. But right now i guess you have to stick to the existing tools

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll keep an eye on the rfc.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start from basics. What is the data type of template? If you create a new HTML file for import in existing folder and do some analysis on it, this is what you will find as below:

[image]

So, if you want to do something like this, you need to return a function by passing that string of template. According to docs, `render()` is

> For complex tasks like conditionally rendering a template or importing a custom one, use render() to override standard rendering functionality. This function gets invoked after connectedCallback() and must return a valid HTML template.

So, if you want to dynamically create template you need to understand what that override is. Even if you are able to override it and create template, it would be hugely complicated task to implement onclick/action handlers. So, recommended not to do that.

**So, what else can we do to have some sort of dynamic nature?**
**Short Answer: you can extend custom component.**

Use Case: If you create a generic LWC component, developers can extend that component and add extra functionality on top of that.

```
export default class Poc extends GenericComponent
```

Here GenericComponent will extend LightningElement, so there will be no problem.